# How can I keep several results of analysis of single project separate in SonarQube?

Tags: sonarqube, version, branch, static-analysis

I want to perform analysis of my project in SonarQube against two different quality profiles and I want to keep the results of analyses separate - I want to be able to browse issues found during analysis against quality profile A and then I want to see the results of analysis performed against profile B

Comment: you can run analyse twice with a custom 'sonar.projectKey' for each analayse, or 'sonar.branch' but it's deprecated since SQ6.7